# DRF: viewsets lookup_field ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm migrating my DRF from generics to viewsets, but I receive this error:

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "monument-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

This is my urls.py

```
from app.api import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'monuments', views.MonumentsViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

This is my viewset

```
from app.api import serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets


class MonumentsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.MonumentSerializer
    queryset = serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

And finally here my serializer

```
from app.api import models
from rest_framework import serializers


class MonumentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Monument
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: why for the field `images` you use link to the `monument`?

Comment: @BearBrown is a mistake, but if I remove this parameter, it gives me this error 
`assert self.view_name is not None, 'The view_name argument is required.'`

Comment: Can you show your models?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `lookup_field = 'id'`. I don't know why this happens, but it worked when I copied your code.

P.S Your error says, you incorrectly configured 'lookup_field'